# How do I get images to fit inside a panel in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I have some UI panels laid out with layout groups and I wish to have images inside the panels.
How do I go about doing this?
I am aware that sprite masks exist but unsure if I can get the size of the panels to drive the bounding area of the mask.
The panels are variable in size since I would like the UI to work on any aspect ratio so I can't just use a static object for the sprite mask.

[My UI Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Od1tb.png)

I would like these images to keep their original aspect ratio but be cropped to the size of the panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the panel gameobject you can add a [RectMask2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-RectMask2D.html) component.

Make sure the image is a child of the panel and add the [AspectRatioFitter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-AspectRatioFitter.html) with a AspectMode "Envelope Parent" and the aspect ratio of the image.